# How to turn off error reporting by Eclipse for .md files

Tags: eclipse, github, markdown

When there is a **README.md** file from **GitHub**,
my Eclipse always shows errors on "Footnote missing",
while the grammar in the md file is correct.

How can I turn off the error reporting on a specific file or files which have specific suffix or...?

Answer (score 4):

[image: Eclipse Problems View]

[image: Eclipse Problems Configure Contents]

This should turn off error reporting for .md files. You might have to restart eclipse if you still see the error some other view/perspective like Package Explorer/Navigator.

Comment: This fixes the problems view, but my Package Explorer still has a red mark on my .md file.  Looked in Validation settings, but no joy.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse Oxygen I solved this issue by uninstalling only Mylyn WikiText plugin.

**Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> Installed**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to come from [mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/): see "[404095: [Markdown] Add support for links and images](http://git.eclipse.org/c/mylyn/org.eclipse.mylyn.docs.git/commit?id=aea430d058cda2ad9d99ba4b05e91cb9b9c2f5a0)"

```
LinkDefinitionValidationRule.missing=Footnote ''{0}'' is missing.
```

Check if [disabling WikiText for files](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/FAQ#How_do_I_enable.2Fdisable_WikiText_extensions_to_Mylyn.3F) could help.

> Open the Mylyn Task Repositories view, right-click your `task repository` and select `Properties` from the context menu.
>   In the properties dialog choose the `Editor settings` (you may need to click on it to expand the section).
>
> To disable WikiText for your repository, select `Plain Text`.

Comment: @kensuke1984 What exact version of Eclipse are you using? Is there Mylyn included in your distro?

Comment: Yeah, I should have written it.. sorry.

Comment: Mine is Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers  Mars latest one 4.5.1

Answer (score 1):

> Adding a \ before the problematic part should solve the problem.

I had a problem with a line like this:
`python logproccli.py [-h] [-l LOGS] [-t TEMPLATE] [-p PARSER]`

Where each argument had a swirly line underneath it saying for example
"Footnote '-l LOGS' is missing."

A solution I found is adding `\` before it:
`python logproccli.py [-h] \[-l LOGS] \[-t TEMPLATE] \[-p PARSER]`

Strangely I had to add it before the LOGS, TEMPLATE and PARSER.
Anyway that "solved" the problem of the error without uninstalling anything.
And that `\\` doesn't show up in the result in the web.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the mylyn plugin that comes default with the normal Java Eclipse version. In Eclipse `Neon`, you can uninstall Mylyn via the `Eclipse Installation Details` view. Just select `Help` ==> `Installation Details`, select the components to want to uninstall, and click `Uninstall...`. Once uninstalled, the "footnote missing" error on the README will go away!

[image: Eclipse Installation Details View]

Comment: This will only work for folks who don't rely on Mylyn. :(

Answer (score 0):

"Footnote missing" errors appear when there are two words surrounded by square brackets.

The simplest solution for removing these errors is to protect the hooks with backslashes.

Example:

```
[Tag1][Tag2]Plop
```

becomes

```
\[Tag1\]\[Tag2\]Plop
```